# Bring a single point forward for display

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend, display

I am attempting to display various shellfish species on a map. The shellfish layer is organized so that the species display in the desired order on the legend. However, the result is that one point is blocked by another, circled in red below. I can't change the symbology or the order of the legend. Is there a way to select an individual point and bring it to the front?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3 btw. My first idea is to create the legend to look exactly how I need and then convert it to a graphic. After which I can change the order of the species within the layer without it effecting the legend. My other idea is to add the layer in the second time, only display the category that is being covered, and place this on top of the first layer. I suppose either will work but is there a better way to solve this problem? [image]

Comment: Do you want to make *all* "Sea Scallops, Qualitative" points show up on top, or just that one point you have circled? If it's the former, you can do that without affecting the legend. If it's the latter, you can't.

Comment: I was doubtful but hopeful there was a way to bring a single point forward.  Bringing all the "Sea Scallops, Qualitative" to the top without changing the legend will certainly solve the display issue in this case.

Comment: If you aren't concerned with severing the tie between the legend and the dataset, you can "convert the legend to graphics." That leaves you free to mess around with the map's symbology display ordering, without affecting the ordering in the legend.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post I have considered converting the legend to a graphic. This isn't ideal because I would like to be able to turn on/off layers as needed for various displays.  This is an option but I'm looking for alternatives if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To alter the draw level of all the records in a feature class go to *Layer Properties*, select the *Advanced* drop-down menu, choose *Symbol Levels*.  In the Symbol Level's dialog box check *Draw this layer using the symbol levels specified below*.  Highlight Seas Scallops, Qualitative and use the arrows to move that row to the top.  Hit *OK*.

If you just want to put that one point on top then select/highlight the point. From the Layer Properties select Selection.  Next, select *Create Layer from Selected Point*.  This will make an in-memory layer of that selected record that you can move to the top of the table of contents.

Answer (score -1):

Try selecting all, deleting, and then undo.  Works every time.